# Expected value of a dice game

Tags: expected-value, dice

> Consider a fair 6-sided die. If you roll a 1,2,3 you increment your score by 1 and roll again. If you roll a 4,5, the game terminates and your payoff for the game is your accumulated score. If you roll a 6, the game terminates and your payoff is nothing.

If we define $N$ to be the number of rolls to get a success (termination state), then we know $E[N] = 2$. The accumulated score is 1 less of this, so it's just 1. The expected payoff is thus $\frac{2}{3}$ since when terminating, 2 out of the 3 states result in profit and the other does not. I know this is the correct answer.

However, I tried a different approach for this problem, and I don't know why it's not working.
Let $P$ be the payoff.

Then we have the following

$$
E[P] = \sum_{i=1}^6 E[P|E_1]P(E_1) \\
P(E_1) = \frac{1}{6}
$$
where $E_i$ is the event of rolling $i$.

We know that

$$
E[P|E_1] = E[P|E_2] = E[P|E_3] = 1 + E[P] \\ 
E[P|E_4] = E[P|E_5] = E[P] \\
E[P|E_6] = 0
$$

If you plug this in and solve for $E[P]$, you get $E[P] = 3$. What is wrong with this latter approach? I suspect it's something to do with my conditional expectations, but those seem right to me.

Comment: I am not clear on what you are doing but I know if you go by expectation, it will lead to GM and AGM series and then yes the answer comes to $\frac{2}{3}$..

Comment: @MathLover I am applying the law of total expectation by conditioning over the 6 disjoint events and trying to figure out the the conditional expectation given each disjoint event. Isn't a valid approach?